# Have unwanted space in the top of my slider image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I implemented a slider on one of my sites but there is a lot of unwanted space above my slider. As you can see the space between the bike image and the menu bar, I was wondering if there was any way to remove this so that the bike image is below the menu bar. I tried looking if it was the height set for the slider but I don't think it is.

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Croydon Cycles</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="shop-style.css">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="parallax.min.js"></script>
</head>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>

                <nav>

                    <div class="menu-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="logo">
                            LOGO
                    </div>

                    <div class="menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>

        </header>


<div class="slideshow-container">


        <div class="myslides fade">

        <div class="numbers">1 / 4</div>

        <div class="slider-1"><img class="Fit" src="images/slider-1.jpg"></div>

        <div class="caption">Text 1</div>

        </div>


        <div class="myslides fade">

        <div class="numbers">2 / 4</div>

        <div class="slider-2"><img src="images/2.jpg"></div>

        <div class="caption">Text 2</div>

        </div>


        <div class="myslides fade">

        <div class="numbers">3 / 4</div>

        <div><img src="images/3.jpg"></div>

        <div class="caption">Text 3</div>

        </div>


        <div class="myslides fade">

        <div class="numbers">4 / 4</div>

        <div><img src="images/4.jpg"></div>

        <div class="caption">Text 4</div>

        </div>


        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>

        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>


        </div>

        <br>


        <div style="text-align:center">

        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 

        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 

        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 

        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 

        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">

        var slideIndex = 1;

        showSlide(slideIndex);


        function plusSlides(n){

        showSlide(slideIndex += n);

        }


        function currentSlide(n) {

        showSlide(slideIndex = n);

        }


        function showSlide(n){

        var i;

        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("myslides");

        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");

        if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1};

        if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length};

        for (i=0;i<slides.length;i++) {

        slides[i].style.display = "none";

        };

        for (i=0;i<dots.length;i++) {

        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active","");

        };

        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";

        }



        </script>

        <div class="content">
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Menu-toggle button

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
                $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
        });
    });

    // Scrolling Effect

    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop()) {
                $('nav').addClass('black');
        }

        else {
                $('nav').removeClass('black');
        }
    })


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: verdana,sans-serif;

    margin: 0;

}

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(hero.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}

.content {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 4em auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
}


.logo {
    line-height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 46px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;
    z-index:2;
}

nav ul {
    line-height: 60px;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 40px;
    transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-icon {
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 786px) {

    .logo {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          margin-top: 16px;
    }

    nav ul {
          max-height: 0px;
          background: #000;
    }

    nav.black ul {
          background: #000;
    }

    .showing {
          max-height: 34em;
    }

    nav ul li {
          box-sizing: border-box;
          width: 100%;
          padding: 24px;
          text-align: center;
    }

    .menu-icon {
          display: block;
    }

}

body{
    font-family: verdana,sans-serif;

    margin: 0;

}

.slideshow-container{

    width: 800px;

    position: relative;

    margin: auto;


}

.numbers{

position: absolute;

top: 0;

color: #f2f2f2;

padding: 8px 12px;

font-size: 12px;

}

.myslides{

display: none;

}

.prev , .next{

position: absolute;

top: 50%;

font-size: 18px;

font-weight: bold;

padding: 16px;

margin-top: -22px;

border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;

color: #fff;

cursor: pointer;

}

.next{

right: 0;

border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;

}

.prev:hover,.next:hover{

background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

}

.caption{

text-align: center;

position: absolute;

bottom: 8px;

width: 100%;

color: #f2f2f2;

font-size: 15px;

padding: 8px 22px;

}

.dots{

width: 13px;

height: 13px;

background: gray;

display: inline-block;

border-radius: 50%;

cursor: pointer;

}

.fade{

animation-name:fade;

animation-duration:1.5s;

}

@keyframes fade{

from {opacity: 0.4;}

to {opacity: 1;}

}

.active, .dot:hover {

background-color: #333;

}

.slider-1 {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:0;
}

.Fit {

    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    z-index:0;  

}
```

Comment: Please make this editable on jsfiddle or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that on you're CSS the header has a height of 100vh...
Just reduce or remove the amount.

```
header {
width: 100%;
/* height: 100vh; */
background: url(hero.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
background-size: cover;
}
```

See here: [jsfidde](https://jsfiddle.net/bhpf5rw0/68/)

Comment: I found the problem in no time with the help of the Chrome DevTools. You should have a look [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)

Comment: Thanks for the help.